# didBeginContact not called when contact is made

Tags: swift, swift3

When two of my SKSpriteNodes touch the didBeginContact function isn't called:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let bodyA = contact.bodyA
    let bodyB = contact.bodyB

    print("Called")

    if bodyA.categoryBitMask == 1 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 2 || bodyA.categoryBitMask == 2 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 1{

    //End
        print("contact")
        _ = GameScene4(fileNamed: "GameScene4.sks")
```

Comment: Have you implemented/inherited from SKPhysicsContactDelegate?

Comment: yes I have @MadhupSinghYadav

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode8.0 Swift3.0 you should use this.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {}
```

Comment: It is still not called